# Find the center of circle that touch both sides of rectangle

Tags: geometry

I have a rectangle and a known point ***b*** at *x, y* position as shown in the picture below.
I want to find the center of the circle (***a***) that touches both sides of the rectangle and pass through point ***b***.
[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I'm a developer and need this for specific task, my math background does not help

Comment: Three points define a circle and we have only one fixed point. This may not have  a single solution

Comment: What do you know about $b$?  Its distance from the corner of the rectangle?  To solve the question, call the radius of the circle $r$:  the distance from $a$ to the corner is both $r$ plus the distance from $b$ to the corner,  and the diagonal of a square side $r$, so you can solve for $r$ and use that to find the location of $a$

Comment: @Henry I know the x,y position of b. I'll update the question to clarify that

Comment: Do you know for certain that the point $b$ lies along a 45° line bisecting one of the rectangle's corners?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you draw a radius from the center to the side of the rectangle, you'll get right isosceles triangle with legs equal to radius $r$. Thus, $r\sqrt2=r+b$ where b is the distance from point $b$ to the vertex of the rectangle. From here you can find that $r=\frac{b}{\sqrt2-1}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $r$ be the radius of the circle;  this is what we want to find.  Let $d$ be the orthogonal distance of point $b$ from the edges of the rectangle.

Draw a square with one corner at $a$ and the other corner shared with the rectangle.  By definition, this line has length $r$, since it's a radius of the circle.  Draw a line segment parallel to a side of the square passing through $b$.  Using our knowledge of 45-45-90 triangles, we can see that the length of this line segment is $r/\sqrt{2} + d$.  But this must be the same length as the side of the square.

Take it from there.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So you know the distance from corner to point **b** as $x$.

Given the triangle below, where $r$ is the radius of the circle (unknown) this $x$ must equal to the hypotenuse minus the radius.

$$ x = \sqrt{2}\, r - r $$

[image: fig]

Solve for the radius

$$ r = \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}-1} $$

Once the radius is known then point **a** is at exactly $r$ to the right and $r$ below the corner.

Answer (score 0):

Let $r$ be the circle's radius. The circle's center is $r$ apart from both top and left side of the rectangle, as well as from the $b$ point. So – assuming the upper-left corner an origin of the coordinate system – coordinates of $a$ are $(r,r)$ such that $$(x_a-x_b)^2+(y_a-y_b)^2 = r^2$$ that is $$(r-x_b)^2+(r-y_b)^2 = r^2.$$
This simplifies to $$r^2 - 2(x_b+y_b)\,r + ({x_b}^2+{y_b}^2) = 0$$
which is a simple quadratic equation with a single unknown $r$.

HTH.

Comment: will it make a difference if the coordinate system origin is the bottom-left corner?

Comment: Yup, you'll have to take the rectangle's height into account, because the $a$ position depends on it.